# SSD not working after cloning with dd

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, ssd, dd

I was trying to clone a partition from my HDD hard drive to an SSD on another laptop.
With dd I made a copy of the partition:

```
dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/img.dd
```

and then on the other laptop from a live cd I tried to restore:

```
dd if=/img.dd of=/dev/nvme0n1p5
```

After the restoration I canceled it because I did not see progress (after that use status = progress)

After that when I tried to restore again about 60% (of progress) it stopped with error.
After this I couldn't even create a new partition table using gparted.
I tried to install Windows but it doesn't even recognize the SSD anymore, it's like it doesn't exist.
Linux fdisk -l doesn't recognize it either

**UPDATE**

The gparted error was similar to the following one, I do not have the exact output because it was for a live cd and now the live cd does not recognize the disk and I cannot format the partition with gparted

```
mkfs.ext4 -F -O ^64bit -L '' '/dev/xxx' 00:01:39 ( ERROR )
64-bit filesystem support is not enabled. The larger fields afforded by this feature enable full-strength checksumming. Pass -O 64bit to rectify.
(...)

Warning, had trouble writing out superblocks.
```

**UPDATE 2**

The last thing i did was:

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=500M count=1
```

to the full disc, that may affect something :(?

**UPDATE 3  answer to @Daniel B**

This is the output of fdisk -l from a live cd:

```
root@mint:/home/mint# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1890041856 bytes, 3691488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 14.6 GiB, 15627976704 bytes, 30523392 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x09bebfcf

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          0 3855295 3855296  1.9G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2       3843044 3847715    4672  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Only the USB is listed (16GB - /dev/sda), it is like the SSD is not there.
The same happens from a Windows installation disc.

Does this mean the SSD was completely broken? Can I do something to verify if it has a solution?

Comment: In order to help we would need to know what that error was exactly

Comment: If the smart still fine, then you can't say the SSD is broken, it's just maybe wrong data copy or other error. Please attach more error log.

Comment: I updated the question, but the problem is now the disk is not listed, it is as if it is not connected. How can I get some information about your status?

Comment: I updated my question with my final operation

Comment: Are you sure the target partition is large enough? // Instead of overwriting the SSD with zeros, use TRIM. // Also, what exactly do you mean by `fdisk -l` not recognizing it? Please provide the exact command line and output.

Comment: @DanielB The partition on the HDD was 50 GB, on the SSD it had a 110 GB partition, so I guess size wasn't the problem. I updated the question with the output of fdisk